# Unable to install VSIX in VS 2012 & Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-10, vsix

I am trying to install RXX(VSIX Isntaller) in windows 10 & VS 2012. But it gives error as below

```
The extension 'Razor(cshtml) pre-processor requires a version of the .NET framework that is not installed.
```

It is working properly in Win 7 ( .NET Framework 4.5 ). When I tried to install .NET framework 4.5 in Win 10, its no allowing to do the same.

Can anyone suggest anything for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I expect the VSIX manifest to reference a specific .NET framework version and doesn't specify a range. Since .NET 4.6 replaces 4.5 it may cause these type of issues.

Extract the VSIX using your favorite extraction tool (it's a zip file), edit the manifest file by removing or updating the dependencies specified and zip it back up.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install the extension was executing the VSIXInstaller.exe as administrator and passing the VSIX file as parameters. To do that, follow this procedure:

1. Open a CMD window as Administrator
2. Go to Common, IDE folder of the VS 2015 installation. In my case:

CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE

3. Execute the installer passing the VSIX file as parameter. In my case:

VSIXInstaller.exe c:\AppBuilder.vsix

Finally, the installer will start the installation!

I hope it helps you

[Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/visual-studio-extension-is-not-installing-on-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-windows-10-enterprise#umOOjsHKYUehBrGdQijFvA)